# Attempt to call local 'callback' (a nil value) error while trying to train SeGAN model

Tags: deep-learning, lua, callback, apply

I am trying to implement the "SeGAN: Segmenting and Generating the invisible" paper on ubuntu 18.04 with Geforce RTX 2060. I have installed the Driver, CUDA, cuDNN, Torch7 and dependencies and downloaded and extracted the dataset and weights folders and made a link to them.
I tried to train the model with this line of code:

```
th main.lua -baseLR 1e-3 -end2end -istrain "train"
```

But I got this error:

```
define model netG...    
/home/darya/distro/install/bin/luajit: /home/darya/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Module.lua:352: attempt to call local 'callback' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    /home/darya/distro/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/Module.lua:352: in function 'apply'
    /home/darya/SeGAN/networks/End2EndNetwork.lua:81: in function 'defineG'
    /home/darya/SeGAN/networks/End2EndNetwork.lua:130: in function 'init_networks'
    /home/darya/SeGAN/networks/End2EndNetwork.lua:343: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    main.lua:265: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...rya/distro/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x55e8fde0f570
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong and since I don't have much experience I am confused.
Can someone help me to fix this problem, please? I appreciate it so much.

[github repository for SeGAN segmenting and generating the invisible](https://github.com/ehsanik/SeGAN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the linked GitHub repo:

[End2EndNetwork.lua line 81](https://github.com/ehsanik/SeGAN/blob/d29e0a5ac08f093b87dc82af3707d50107900d04/networks/End2EndNetwork.lua#L81)

```
netG:apply(weights_init)
```

`weights_init` is supposed to be a function value but is nil.

Which in `Module:apply` causes `callback(self)` in Torch nn's [Module.lua Line352](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/872682558c48ee661ebff693aa5a41fcdefa7873/Module.lua#L352) to fail.

Looks like someone has to implement that function.

Like in https://github.com/phillipi/pix2pix/blob/89ff2a81ce441fbe1f1b13eca463b87f1e539df8/train.lua, which https://github.com/ehsanik/SeGAN/blob/d29e0a5ac08f093b87dc82af3707d50107900d04/networks/End2EndNetwork.lua#L73 refers to.

where

```
local function weights_init(m)
   local name = torch.type(m)
   if name:find('Convolution') then
      m.weight:normal(0.0, 0.02)
      m.bias:fill(0)
   elseif name:find('BatchNormalization') then
      if m.weight then m.weight:normal(1.0, 0.02) end
      if m.bias then m.bias:fill(0) end
   end
end
```